# Symfony3 embed Controllers in a Template

Tags: symfony, twig, sidebar, extends

I have a sidebar.html.twig template that is recurred in every page so is in my base.html.twig root template. It contains logic because the menu of my sidebar is filled dynamically from a function that calls the database in my controller.

My problem is my sidebar template must extends the content block of my base layout. Here is my code :

My function that call the database :

```
public function filterByBrandAction()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArticleBundle:Article');
    $brands = $repository->getBrand();

    return $this->render('sidebar.html.twig', [
        'brands' => $brands
    ]);
}
```

My sidebar template :

```
<div class="uk-offcanvas-content">

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    <div id="offcanvas-push" uk-offcanvas="mode: push; overlay: true">
        <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar">
            <h2>LA FRIPERIE</h2>
            <button class="uk-offcanvas-close" type="button" uk-close></button>

            <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default uk-nav-parent-icon" uk-nav>
                <li class="uk-nav-header">Fripes</li>

                <li><a href="#">Toutes les fripes</a></li>

                <li class="uk-parent">
                    <a href="#">Fripes par marque</a>
                    <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                        <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid">

                            {% for brand in brands %}
                                <label><input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox"> {{ brand.brand }}</label>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="uk-parent">
                    <a href="#">Fripes par catégories</a>
                    <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="uk-parent">
                    <a href="#">Fripes par prix</a>
                    <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Fripes solidaires</a></li>
                <li class="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Vendre ses fripes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Donner ses fripes</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my base template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>{% block title %}La Friperie{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/global.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.30/css/uikit.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        {% block navbar %}
            <nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-margin" uk-navbar uk-sticky="show-on-up: true; animation: uk-animation-slide-top; bottom: #bottom; media: 640;">
                <div class="uk-navbar-left">
                    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-small-right" type="button" uk-toggle="target: #offcanvas-push">Menu</button>
                    <a class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="#">LA FRIPERIE</a>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-navbar-right">
                    <div>
                        <a class="uk-navbar-toggle" uk-search-icon href="#"></a>
                        <div class="uk-drop" uk-drop="mode: click; pos: left-center; offset: 0">
                            <form class="uk-search uk-search-navbar uk-width-1-1">
                                <input class="uk-search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block sidebar %}
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            {{ render(controller('ArticleBundle:Article:filterByBrand')) }}
        {% endblock %}


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.30/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.30/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `{% block content %}` at the line 3 of my sidebar template should match with the `{% block content %}` of my base template in order that all work perfectly.
But I don't know how to do to extends the `{% block content %}` of my base template, the simple `{% extends base.html.twig %}` in my sidebar template don't works.

If you have an idea I'll take it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution, I just move

```
`<div class="uk-offcanvas-content">

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}`
```

in the base.html.twig template like that I no longer need to include the content block in any templates.

Answer (score 0):

Will the content of `{% block content %}`change on your sidebar ?

1. If no, you can do this :

   ```
           {% block content %}{% endblock %}
           {% block sidebar %}
               {{ render(controller('ArticleBundle:Article:filterByBrand')) }}
           {% endblock %}
   ```

   and remove it from your sidebar.html.twig.
2. If yes, you have to split the code of the both anyway, because a child can not change the values of other children of the same parent directly. Try :

   `{{ include 'content....' }}` or `{{ render(controller(content)) }}`

on the main template (**block sidebar**).

Comment: Yes the `{% block content %}` change dynamically by the database.

Comment: and it is override by every `{% block content %}` of each children of base template. My problem is that his position in the sidebar template must be placed just below of the element`<div class="uk-offcanvas-content">` at the line 1 because of working of the UI framework

Comment: So the block `{% block content %}` of the sidebar template must be the same `{% block content %}` as base template. And with an `include` as you say I don't see how to do.

Comment: Good, you found the solution yourself. :)

Comment: Do not forget to close the <div class="uk-offcanvas-content">....</div>

Comment: Yes I saw it , Thanks !